# Validation in Model giving undefine nil []

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have the following code which is running a validation on all snippet content to check the word count against a constant but I keep getting the following error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #36):

current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count
errors.add(:base, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']
end
```

Here is the full code from the model (snippet.rb)

```
BOOK_SIZE = { 
    0 => {"per" => 5, "total" => 50},
    1 => {"per" => 6 , "total" => 60},
    2 => {"per" => 7, "total" => 70}
  }


def size_limit
  book_limit = self.book.size

  word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size

  current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count
  binding.pry
  errors.add(:base, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']
end
```

Because snippets is a child of books, here is the `word_count` listed in book.rb:

```
def get_word_count
  @word_count = []
  self.snippets.each do |c|
    @word_count << c.content.scan(/\w+/).size
  end
  @word_count = @word_count.inject(:+)
end
```

EDIT: Pry Debug

```
   31:  def size_limit
 => 32:   binding.pry
    33:   book_limit = self.book.size
    34: 
    35:   word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size
    36:  
    37:   current_snippets_size = (self.book.get_word_count || 0) + word_count
    38:  
    39:   errors.add(:base, "Content size is too big") unless word_count < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] && current_snippets_size < BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']
    40: end 

[1] pry(#<Snippet>)> p book_limit
nil
=> nil
[2] pry(#<Snippet>)> p word_count
nil
=> nil
[3] pry(#<Snippet>)> errors.any?
=> false
[4] pry(#<Snippet>)> errors.blank?
=> true
```

I tried using PRY but I am still new to the debugging side, some documents describing the best way to walk through PRY debugging would be really useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you inspect BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per'] and BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total'] with your PRY debugger?

Comment: Did you try `def nil.[] *args; end`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify whether these lines always returns you a value :

> book_limit = self.book.size
>
> word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size

if so they may be returning a string object, make it `to_i`

`book_limit = self.book.size.to_i`

`word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size.to_i`

Comment: How would I check the output in the console?

Comment: either use a debugging tool (i personally use `pry`) or in `rails c` call the model method from console as `ModelName.action_name` use `p book_limit` and `p word_count`in your action to know what values are they returning

Comment: Amit I updated the question, I'm using pry but this is the first time using it to debug.

Comment: define the `binding.pry` after the `word_count = self.content.scan(/\w+/).size` stmt. and just check for `book_limit` and `word_count` variables

Comment: Yep all returning the correct values, even current_snippets_size the error is in the last line.

Comment: did u check for `BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]` or `BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per']` or  `BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['total']` values individually, tell me what you get in this variables.

Comment: pry(#<Snippet>)> p BOOK_SIZE[book_limit]['per']
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):45:in `size_limit This is where the error lies but why is isn't it pulling the constant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40115/discussion-between-amit-karsale-and-shaun-frost-duke-jackson)

Answer (score 1):

```
errors.add(:base, "book size is out of range") unless [0, 1, 2].include?(self.book.size)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this. Could you explain?

Comment: @ShaunFrostDukeJackson what Mori is saying here is unless the hash key is either 0,1 or 2 and that object exists and get the reference to the current object then print out "Here's the problem."

Comment: I tried this method and it didn't work. The hash 0,1,2 is already listed in the column size. Column size is a string because its using collection select from a form. The model converts it into an 0,1,2. The total needs to be shown for the total amount of words in every snippet not just the current one. User can have many snippets.